# PHP Script Works on One Domain but Not the Other

Tags: php, apache, dns, captcha

I have a PHP script that prints a random number for use as a captcha code. However, for the life of me, I can't figure out why it works on one domain but not the other, even though the servers have the same exact specs.

Displays a captcha code:
http://www.unitedfleetparts.com/php-/captcha_code.php

Displays NOTHING, even though it's the same exact script:
http://www.uatparts.com/php-/captcha_code.php

Please help me figure out how I can get this PHP script to work on my second domain. Any help is appreciated.

PHP Script:

```
<?php
session_start();
$image_width = 120;
$image_height = 40;
$characters_on_image = 6;
$font = './monofont.ttf';

$possible_letters = '23456789bcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyz';
$random_dots = 0;
$random_lines = 20;
$captcha_text_color="0x142864";
$captcha_noice_color = "0x142864";

$code = '';

$i = 0;
while ($i < $characters_on_image) { 
$code .= substr($possible_letters, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible_letters)-1), 1);
$i++;
}

$font_size = $image_height * 0.75;
$image = @imagecreate($image_width, $image_height);

$background_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);

$arr_text_color = hexrgb($captcha_text_color);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, $arr_text_color['red'], 
    $arr_text_color['green'], $arr_text_color['blue']);

$arr_noice_color = hexrgb($captcha_noice_color);
$image_noise_color = imagecolorallocate($image, $arr_noice_color['red'], 
        $arr_noice_color['green'], $arr_noice_color['blue']);

for( $i=0; $i<$random_dots; $i++ ) {
imagefilledellipse($image, mt_rand(0,$image_width),
 mt_rand(0,$image_height), 2, 3, $image_noise_color);
}

for( $i=0; $i<$random_lines; $i++ ) {
imageline($image, mt_rand(0,$image_width), mt_rand(0,$image_height),
 mt_rand(0,$image_width), mt_rand(0,$image_height), $image_noise_color);
}

$textbox = imagettfbbox($font_size, 0, $font, $code); 
$x = ($image_width - $textbox[4])/2;
$y = ($image_height - $textbox[5])/2;
imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, $x, $y, $text_color, $font , $code);

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($image);
imagedestroy($image);
$_SESSION['6_letters_code'] = $code;

function hexrgb ($hexstr)
{
  $int = hexdec($hexstr);

  return array("red" => 0xFF & ($int >> 0x10),
               "green" => 0xFF & ($int >> 0x8),
               "blue" => 0xFF & $int);
}
?>
```

Comment: So the php version and configuration is identical? e.g. both are the same version of PHP? both have the gd library installed and enabled?

Comment: And if you have logging enabled (if you don't, why not?), what do the logs show?

Comment: Mark, thanks for your post. Where are the logs located? It is not causing an error log (I checked using FileZilla FTP).

Comment: First place to check would be your webserver logs; the webserver config file should tell you where they are being stored