# AngularJS works on one domain, but not another

Tags: php, angularjs

I have been developing an AngularJS App at one domain, say experiment.example.com/application, then copying it over to another, say schooldomain.com/application. I've done this in stages once I have an element working. All has been going well, but as the application has got larger, I've found that things don't always work on the school domain.

Below is one of many functions which 'get' data from data-process.php, all others of which work on both sites.

I have tried playing with permissions, and have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21026231/php-script-works-on-one-domain-but-not-the-other) but not sure if relevant.

My question is, what steps should I follow to resolve this. Thanks for any help.

```
    $scope.oneQ = function(title,attempt,csv,status) {
    $scope.quizinfo = "";
    $http.get('inc/data-process.php?v=oneQ', {params:{title:title,attempt:attempt,csv:csv,status:status}}).then(function(response) {
        $scope.quizinfo = response.data.records;
    });
```

Comment: Well, did you copy the serverside part of the project as well? If you only copy the angularJS part, and you do a `get` request with a relative path like `inc/data-process.php`, the request will fail.

Comment: Yes, all files copied over.

Comment: Are you sure your server's running? What error do you get in the dev tools console after the request is triggered?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: Though other functions calling same php file, all work without this error.

Comment: Maybe you're forgetting an authorization header or some sort of token in the http call?

Comment: Thanks - where can I read about this? Though other calls are near identical.

Comment: I'd first check the corresponding endpoint in your PHP files for the http call to `inc/data-process.php?v=oneQ` and see what causes a `403` response.

Comment: It turns out that the 'csv' variable, being a full URL relating to a CSV elsewhere on the web, was causing a 403 on the school site, but not the first domain.